# Hey one undesired error is occuring in mysql

Tags: mysql

I just wrote a query, which was displaying data from mysql perfectly, but after a while when i am running the same query, the output is showing as "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)".

I don't know why it's happening.
I am doing INNER JOIN of two tables.

```
SELECT 
    tbl_customer_conversation.follow_date, 
    tbl_customer_conversation.status, 
    tbl_customer_conversation.user_id 
FROM 
    tbl_customer_conversation 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_lms_user 
ON 
    tbl_customer_conversation.user_id=tbl_lms_user.user_id 
where 
    tbl_customer_conversation.follow_date= DATE(NOW()) 
AND 
    tbl_lms_user.first_name = 'Be';
```

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question.

Comment: phpmyadmin is saying "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ". But the data exists in these tables. and few minutes earlier everything was working fine

Comment: if it worked a while ago, maybe this part is the culprit?     tbl_customer_conversation.follow_date= DATE(NOW())

Comment: yes, you're right. my mistake.

Comment: -1 for stupid title. BTW, which error is ever desired?

Comment: @ŁukaszRysiak: That should be an answer, not comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it worked a while ago, maybe this part is the culprit?

`tbl_customer_conversation.follow_date= DATE(NOW())`

Following @ypercube comment and [this question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78895/how-to-handle-an-answer-as-a-comment) I'm adding this as an answer since it solved question.

Comment: fixed link - SO editor is strange.